# Getting variables from a Bootstrap slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have to get a variable from a price range slider for my webshop. I want to echo the value in PHP. This is the code in my test.php file:

```
<script>
    var slidervalue = $('#output').val();
</script>

<?php
    echo "<script>document.writeln(slidervalue);</script>";
?>
```

And this is the code in the bootstrap-slider.js file:

```
$(function() {
    $("#pricelimit")
    .slider({})
    .on('slide', function() {
        $('#output').html(this.value);
    })
    .trigger('slide');
});
```

And this is the code of the slider itself:

```
<input id="pricelimit" type="text" class="span2" value=""
    data-slider-min="10" 
    data-slider-max="200" 
    data-slider-step="5" 
    data-slider-value="[20,100]"/>
```

However, on the page, it says 'undefined'. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Don't you need to pass some arguments into the slider method? `.slider({})`

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have included jQuery library in test.php or if it is included in another file, check if JQuery is included there too.

Then, remove the **var** from  `var slidervalue = $('#output').val();`from test.php.

Also you can directly access the value using php's `$_GET['somename']` by first adding the "name" attribute in the input. `name="somename"`